# Ошибка autoload в 92five app

Tags: php, autoload

Скачал [92five app](https://github.com/chintanbanugaria/92five) , но при запуске на XAMPP возникли следующие ошибки, хотя Composer я устанавливал

> Warning:
>   require_once(D:\xampp\htdocs\92five-master\vendor/composer/autoload_real.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\92five-master\vendor\autoload.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'D:\xampp\htdocs\92five-master\vendor/composer/autoload_real.php'
>   (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\92five-master\vendor\autoload.php on line 5

Ранее редко сталкивался с php, не могу понять в чём беда. 
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: https://github.com/chintanbanugaria/92five/blob/master/README.md убедитесь что установлены все зависимости грант, и если что пробуйте написать в поддержку, так как ошибка или из-за неправильной установки или от того что где-то баг, я склоняюсь к неправильности установки

Comment: Суть в том что установки даже не было. В том и беда( По сути я должен запустить приложения и у меня должно открыться окно установки, но заместо этого вылезает эта ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного поэкспериментировав нашел *корень зла* -

```
"pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
```

Эту строку **нужно убрать** из composer.json так как вместо загрузки вылетает ошибка которую получаем от  `artisan` так как он не находит все нужные пакеты на которые ссылаются файлы, в проекте, в дальнейшем, после первого апдейта можно вернуть ее на место.

Находится она в блоке:

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
```

После удаления строки необходимо запустить `composer update`, *из консоли* - он доустановит недостающие пакеты, и запрашиваемый файл(в котором генерируется все классы проекта)

Comment: да, спасибо, действительно  autoload прогрузился, но после всё равно выдаёт ошибку. Появляется красное окно, где написано Whoops! There was an error. После того как коммнетрию строки 110-118 в файле app/start/global.php выходит следующий текст ошибки: 
ErrorException

session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (user).
Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/opt/lampp/temp/)

Comment: @Jonny, это уже другой вопрос который стоит создать отдельно, чтоб в дальнейшем его могли найти. А этот отметьте решенным)

Answer (score -1):

Первая ошибка говорит что по адресу `D:\xampp\htdocs\92five-master\vendor/composer/autoload_real.php` нету файла, а вторая следствие первой

вероятно из-за того что в пути присутствуют как прямые так и обратные слеши

Comment: я просто не пойми какие файлы нужно загрузить, ведь проект итак уже готовый, а в инструкции говорится только о том, чтобы дать разрешение файлам.

Comment: я изменял это, но ошибка оставалась и в ней тупо менялись слеши. Мне только непонятно почему в папке vendor нет папки composer и файла autoload_real.php. Может мне надо его самостоятельно создать?

Comment: я предполагаю что все пути в приложении указаны с такой же ошибкой, вам нужно либо править все пути в приложении либо править настройки сервера

Comment: Warning: require_once(D:\xampp\htdocs\92five-master\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\92five-master\vendor\autoload.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\92five-master\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\92five-master\vendor\autoload.php on line 5

Вот что происходит, когда я меняю слеши. Даже первый файл у меня не проходит.